# Sync email from outlook to pop3 mailbox

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, pop3

I was accessing a customers mailbox for some troubleshooting and I forgot to uncheck the "delete messeges from server" option in outlook so all his emails are gone from the server.

Is there any way to sync them back to the server?

Regards

Jonas

Answer (score 0):

No, if they are deleted from the server they are gone. It might be possible that the provider keeps a backup and is willing to restore the e-mail on the server.

You might want to check if they really are gone, can't you see the mail on a different client?

Comment: well we are the provider and no we do not keep a backup set. And yes they are gone. However I was lucky and we had imap enabled on this particular mailbox so I'll be able to sync them back anyway